# Error when trying to compile a user information list with MySQL using a join and a nested select

Tags: mysql, sql, join, nested

I am wondering why this MySQL query is not working.

MySQL is reporting "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''subscriptions' AS sub INNER JOIN (SELECT `UserID` as uid from `subscriptions` ' at line 1"

Goal: I am trying to get a distinct user information list of all of the users that are in the specified user's rooms.

Table Structure: 
"subscriptions" Table Structure - a table of all of the rooms a user is in
- SubscriptionID (auto increment)
- RoomID
- UserID

"users" Table Structure - a table consisting of user account details
- id (auto increment)
- nickname
- status
- about
- etc..

Query that I have so far:

```
    SELECT * from 'subscriptions' AS sub 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT `UserID` as uid from `subscriptions` WHERE RoomID = sub.RoomID)t on       t.uid = users.id
    WHERE sub.UserID = '1'
```

I have accomplished something that gets user information in the way described above.. However I was looking for a per-say "performance" upgrade. In order to perform an operation similar to the one listed above I must first get a distinct list of all of the rooms a user is in. Then after that, get a distinct list of all the users in that room that the user is in. Then after that - compile all of the members in each room into one list and query the user information table for each found user individually. Surely there is a more efficient and more logical way to accomplish this..

Comment: Select * from subscriptions : use backticks not single quotes

Comment: That was quite the silly error.. However now it is throwing " #1054 - Unknown column 'sub.RoomID' in 'where clause' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do a correlated subquery in the `from` clause.  Your query is:

```
SELECT *
from 'subscriptions sub INNER JOIN
      (SELECT `UserID` as uid
       from `subscriptions`
       WHERE RoomID = sub.RoomID
      ) t
      on t.uid = users.id
WHERE sub.UserID = '1';
```

I'm also fixing the `user.id` to be `sub.id`:

```
SELECT *
from subscriptions sub INNER JOIN
     subscriptions t
     on t.uid = sub.id and t.roomId = sub.RoomId
WHERE sub.UserID = '1';
```

However, I think you want:

```
select *
from subscriptions s
where s.roomId in (select roomId from subscriptions s2 where s2.UserId = '2')
```

Comment: Well that wasn't so hard after all! Thanks. (The last one is exactly what I was looking for)